# CSS3 animation failure

Tags: css-transitions

I am trying to get an animation when you click on the button.
The animation goes from green to red, but when it ends it instantly goes back to the color of the div itself?
so it goes from green to red and then instantly back to green.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to post your code

Answer (score 0):

i hope it helps...

here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rameezrami/8efnztkt or use following code

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.anim-div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-animation-name: color-animation; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: color-animation;
    animation-duration: 6s;
}
.non-anim-div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes color-animation {
    50%  {background-color: red;}
    100% {background-color: green;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes color-animation{
    50%  {background-color: red;}
    100% {background-color: green;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="non-anim-div"></div>
<input type="button" value="Clik here to animate" class="btn"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".btn").click(function(){
$(".non-anim-div").addClass("anim-div");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```